# ASP.net development server needs restart every time

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with my ASP.NET development server. I need to stop before I run my app from  VS Express environment again otherwise it uses a previously rendered version.

I have searched for solutions all over, over a 3-4 month period but nothing, perhaps I am using the wrong words?

Comment: You have a development server which is not your workstation? SO you deploy codes to the server frequently during your development? 
Care to explain what are the symptoms you see/error messages etc? And how do you deploy your applicationto the server?

Comment: Sorry for clarity I am running VS 2008 Express, I click on the "View in Brower" button, which then saves and runs the website, and runs the ASP.NET dev server locally (I think this is the default server on setup) and it runs the website, I can debug etc. However if I make changes I need to then first stop the asp.net dev server and then click the button again, otherwise I get the last render

Answer (score 1):

Do you save your changes in Visual Studio?  (just editing is not enough)

Does your browser perhaps cache the page?  In most browsers, `CTRL-F5` will refresh to browser side cache.

Comment: Yip every time, have tried CTRL-F5, as well, I am currently using chrome, was using opera before, but Ctrl-F5 makes no difference

Comment: MVC project have to restart every single time. You are NOT allowed to modify the code, with the app running. the pause and edit feature(edit and continue) is also very stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to MSDN forums and microsoft knowledge base I found this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911272

Essentially the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode determines how ASP.NET is dealt with as an app on the box setting this to "0" fixed the problem, no need to start and stop every time :)

Explains why a reinstall did not work

Comment: I found that setting FCNMode to 0 caused other errors, but value as 2 works well, and all is working fine now/

Comment: You can read more about this at http://blogs.msdn.com/carloc/archive/2009/09/06/hosting-on-a-unc-share-is-not-supported-for-the-windows-xp-platform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that Cassini (the development web server associated with Visual Studio) doesn't restart if you change certain files, and does restart if you change others.  For example, if you have an HttpModule in the App_Code folder, and you change its code, Cassini will not restart automatically.  However, if you change web.config, then it will.  Sometimes, doing a recompile on the site will fix it, but many times it won't.

I submitted a bug to Microsoft via Connect about this; their response was that the behavior was "as designed."

My solution was to switch to using IIS instead of Cassini -- just configure IIS to point to the development folder, and then change the startup URL to be http://localhost/  Cassini has a bunch of other annoying features too (like no support for compression), so this works better for me.  I can still debug this way, too, so nothing lost.

Having said all of that, if you are *only* changing the .aspx page, then you may have something else going on....

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have reinstalled and nothing change (VS2008) - not a clean install - i.e. uninstall - kill - reinstall, but I had this problem before I re-installed Vista too.

Are you saying install IIS or you an IIS on say my server?

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems when I switched machines. Both machines had Visual Studio 2012 installed (The first one had Windows 7 Ultimate 64, the second one Windows 7 Enterprise N 64). On the second one I always had to restart the Asp.Net development server because the shadow assemblies in Asp.Net temporary files folder were never updated after the page has started.

I solved the issue by explicitly setting 'fcnMode' to default in Web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" fcnMode="Default"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This  worked well for me from Greg Slavec, I then went into the registration key to change the default there to the value "2".   It moves with lightening speed on the login page, but during the Save routine it is still hanging..